# To find all integer solutions using elementary number theory or linear algebra

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

Find all $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb Z^+$ such that $$\frac{x!+y!}{z!}=3^z$$

I was unable to find a nice way to approach the problem. I tried to use the fact that $\frac{x!+y!}{z!}\equiv 1\pmod 2$ but I got nowhere. 
 I also tried the rearrangement $x!\left(1+\frac{y!}{x!}\right)=z!3^z$ by equating $x!$ and $z!$, and was able to get the solution $(1,2,1)$.
Can someone please provide a rigorous solution providing all solutions or proving no further solutions to this equation.

Comment: My computer tells me $(1,2,1)$ is indeed the only solution when $x,y,z<1000$, so you might try to prove that there can be ne other solutions.

Comment: Hint: WLOG assume $x\leq y$ and factor out $\frac{x!}{z!}$ now take cases with $z,x$ and try proving $ (x-z)! = 3^{k}$(where $x \geq z$) .And also use the fact that the product of $n$ consecutive numbers are divisible by $n!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for $x\geq z$

The equation can be factorised as            $$\frac{x!}{z!}(1+\frac{y!}{x!})$$

This implies, $3^{k}=\frac{x!}{z!} (k\leq z)$ or $3^{k}=x(x-1)...(z+1)$
Since $n!$ divides the product of $n$ consecutive integers. $$(x-z)!|3^{k} \rightarrow 0\leq (x-z)\leq 1$$

Case 1: $x=z$

$$3^{x}|1+\frac{y!}{x!}\ \ or\ \ 3^x ∤ (y-x)!$$

So $0 \leq (y-x) \leq 2$ or $y= x,x+1,x+2$ which yields the only solution, $(x,y,z)=(1,2,1)$

Case 2: $x=z+1$

$$3|z\\ \ 3|1+\frac{y!}{(z+1)!}\ \ or\ \ 3 ∤\frac{y!}{(z+1)!}$$

So $1\leq(y-z)\leq 3$ or $y=z+1,z+2,z+3$ from which we get no solutions.

Hence for $x \geq z \ \ \ (1,2,1)$ is the only solution.

Say both $x,y \leq z$

Therefore, max value of the expression is $\frac{2}{z!}$ so $z=2$

It is easy to check that no $x,y$ satisfies this condition.

Comment: If $x < z$, then it's even easier. The left-hand side of the proposition can now be written as 
$$\frac{1 + y (y - 1)\cdots(y - x + 1)}{z (z-1) \cdots (z - x + 1)}$$ 
If $x > 1$, then the numerator is $1 \mod 2$, while the denominator is $0 \mod 2$, and hence this can't even be an integer.